# Radicals of subrings

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

It is known that for a subring $R$ of some (commutative) ring $S$, the nilradical of $R$ $$\text{nil }R=R\cap\text{nil }S.$$ Moreover for Jacobson rings $R\subset S$, this means that the Jacobson radical of $R$ can also be written in this way, i.e., $J(R)=R\cap J(S)$.

**Edit.** Are there separate-case counterexamples where this is not true more generally? For example, (credited to YACP) to show that the Jacobson radical of a subring can properly contain the intersection, consider the following: let $R$ be a local integral domain and $S=R[X]$. Then $J(S)=(0)$ and $J(R)=\mathfrak m$.

What about where the Jacobson radical of a subring does not contain the intersection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $R$ an integral domain, $\mathfrak m$ a maximal ideal, and $S=R_{\mathfrak m}$. Then $J(S)\cap R=\mathfrak m$ and obviously $J(R)$ does not necessarily contain $J(S)\cap R$.

Comment: Sorry about that! I humbly thank your patience for my ineptitude. :) On a belated note, is there a notion for the Jacobson radical of a maximal ideal? I was considering $S$ to be a local ring and $R$ its maximal ideal. Hence $J(S)\cap R=R$ whereas $J(R)$... I dunno.

Comment: Then you have to consider the maximal ideal as a module and use [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304140/the-jacobson-radical-of-a-module-over-commutative-ring), but I don't know how useful is your point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbb Z_4=\left\{0, 1, 2, 3\right\}$ be the residual classes modulo $z$. Considere the matrix ring $S=M_2(\mathbb Z_4)$. Since for a ring $A$ the nilradical of the matrix ring $M_n(A)$ is $M_n(\mathcal N(A))$ where $\mathcal N(A)$ is the nilradical of $A$, it follows that $\mathcal N(M_n(\mathbb Z_4))=M_n(I)$, where $I=\{0, 2\}$. Now, consider the subring

$$R=\left\{\left[\begin{array}{cc}x&y\\0&x\end{array}\right]\;\;x,y\in\mathbb Z_4\right\}.$$

Note that $R$ is commutative. So, the nilradical of $R$ is the set of all nilpotent elements.  We have that

$$w=\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\0&0\end{array}\right]$$
is nilpotent, so is in the radical of $R$. But $w\notin M_n(I) $. Hence $\mathcal N(R)\neq R\cap \mathcal N(S) $