# Maximal ideals generate maximal submodules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $\mathfrak m$ be a maximal ideal of $R$ and $M$ an $R$-module such that $\mathfrak mM\ne M$. Is it true that $\mathfrak mM$ is a maximal submodule of $M$? Thank you.

(I can see this happen in case $M$ is cyclic.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course not! Take $M=R^2$. Then $M/\mathfrak mM$ is an $R/\mathfrak m$-vectorspace of dimension $2$, so there is a proper subspace $N/\mathfrak mM$ of $M/\mathfrak mM$. This shows that $\mathfrak mM\subset N\subset M$.

Comment: Yes, $M=\left\langle(1,0)+mM,(0,1)+mM \right\rangle $. Thank you!

Comment: @ YACP. In case $M$ is radical (i.e. $M$ has no maximal submodule), does we have $mM=M$? (m is maximal ideal of $R$)

Comment: Isn't it even more instructive to consider the case of $R$ being a field and M be an vector space of dimension greater 1.
I know it is a special case of your example but it's simpler.

Comment: @user63895 Have you seen [this topic](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304140/the-jacobson-radical-of-modules-over-commutative-rings)?

Comment: @ YACP. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

For $\mathfrak{m}=0$ the question is: Is $\{0\}$ a maximal subspace in every nontrivial vector space? And this is only true in the 1-dimensional case.