# Why Jacobson radical of a cyclic module over integral domain $R$ such that $\mathrm{Rad}(R)=(0)$ is zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, integral-domain, free-modules

Let $R$ be an integral domain with zero Jacobson radical and $M$ be a free $R$-module. Why Jacobson radical of $M$ is zero? Why $\mathrm{Rad}(Rm)=(0)$ where $m\in M$?

Comment: What is Rad(Rm)

Comment: That is Jacobson radical of $R$-module $Rm$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304140/the-jacobson-radical-of-modules-over-commutative-rings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$\begin{align}\mathrm{Rad}(M) & = \bigcap \{N: M/N\; \text{is a simple module} \} \\
& = \bigcap \{N: M/N\; \text{is a semi-simple module}\}. 
\end{align}$$
And for a maximal ideal, $I_\text{max} \lhd R,$ we have that $M/I_\text{max}M$ is an $R/I_\text{max}$-vector space, and so $M/I_\text{max}M$ is a semi-simple module.

So $\mathrm{Rad}(M) \subseteq \bigcap \{IM : I\; \text{is a maximal ideal of}\; R\}$.

But as $M$ is free, if $\{m_1, ... ,m_n\}$ is a basis for $M$, and $i_1m_1 + \cdots + i_nm_n= j_1m_1 + \cdots +j_nm_n$ then we conclude that $i_k=j_k\; \forall k \in \{1, ..., n\}$.

Hence we see that $$\begin{align}\mathrm{Rad}(M) &\subseteq \bigcap \{IM : I\; \text{is a maximal ideal of}\; R\}\\
& \subseteq\mathrm{Rad}(R)M\\
& =\{0\}\ (\text{by hypothesis}).
\end{align} $$

I don't think that I have used that $R$ is an integral domain here so maybe I have made a mistake but I can't see it... I hope this helps...

Comment: Maybe integral domain is a extra condition. Please tell me for $R/i_{max}$-vector space $M/I_{max}$, Why $M/I_{max}M$ is a semi-simple module?

Comment: @ruhollakh this is because any vector space is a semi-simple module. It is the direct sum of the 1 dimensional subspaces being the spans of the basis elements. As these are 1 dimensional they are simple modules.

Answer (score 0):

A free module is a direct sum of copies of $R$, say
$$
M=R^{(X)}=\{(r_x)_{x\in X}: \operatorname{supp}(r_x)_{x\in X}\text{ is finite}\}
$$
where $\operatorname{supp}(r_x)_{x\in X}$ is the set $\{x\in X:r_x\ne0\}$.

For a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $R$, consider, for $y\in X$,
$$
\mathfrak{m}_y=\{(r_x)_{x\in X}\in M:r_y\in \mathfrak{m}\}
$$
Then $\mathfrak{m}_y$ is a maximal submodule of $F$, as
$$
M/\mathfrak{m}_y\cong R/\mathfrak{m}
$$
Also
$$
\bigcap_{\substack{\mathfrak{m}\text{ maximal}\\y\in X}}M_y=J^{(X)}
$$
where $J=\operatorname{Rad}R$ is the Jacobson radical of $R$. Therefore
$$
\operatorname{Rad}M\subseteq J^{(X)}
$$
In the present case $J=(0)$, so also $\operatorname{Rad}F$ is zero. (Actually, equality holds in general.)

If $m\in F$, then $Rm\cong R$, because a free module is torsion free (here we're using the fact that $R$ is a domain). Therefore $\operatorname{Rad}(Rm)=\{0\}$ by the isomorphism.